# Scrapy Crawled 0 pages failing to download pdf

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy. I am attempting to download this pdf using scrapy. It is not clear to me why it is not working.

```
import scrapy

class Hawaii_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hawaii"
    allowed_domains = ["hawaii.edu"]

    def parse_listing(self, response):
        file_urls = ["http://www2.hawaii.edu/~kinzie/documents/CV%20&%20pubs/Kauhako.pdf"]#[start_url + day + end_url for day in days]
        for url in file_urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.save_pdf)

    def save_pdf(self, response):
        path = self.get_path(response.url)
        with open(path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've provided - there are no `start_urls` or `start_requests()` method defined so no requests are made and nothing is scraped.

Here is a working example downloading the pdf from [here](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~kinzie/documents/CV%20&%20pubs/Kauhako.pdf) and saving it as `test.pdf`:

```
import scrapy


class Hawaii_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hawaii"
    allowed_domains = ["hawaii.edu"]

    def start_requests(self):
        file_urls = ["http://www2.hawaii.edu/~kinzie/documents/CV%20&%20pubs/Kauhako.pdf"]#[start_url + day + end_url for day in days]
        for url in file_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.save_pdf)

    def save_pdf(self, response):
        with open("test.pdf", "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```